# Custom authentication issue in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have added a custom authentication component for a Yii2 RESTful project and it is validating credentials OK but it is not returning the valid User object to \Yii::$app->user

The component looks like this:

```
public function authenticate($user, $request, $response) {

    $bearerToken = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('bearer_token');

    $user = Account::findIdentityByAccessToken($bearerToken);

    return $user;
}
```

And the Account model method looks like this:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $userType = null) {

    return static::findOne(['bearer_token' => $token]);
}
```

I can see $user is the expected record of Account when debugging in the authenticate() method but \Yii::app()->user seems to be a newly instatiated user. \Yii::app()->user->identity is equal to null.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To login user this is not enough:

```
Account::findIdentityByAccessToken($bearerToken);
```

You need to call `$user->login($identity)` inside `authentificate()`. See for example how it's implemented in [yii\web\User](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) [loginByAccessToken()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#loginByAccessToken%28%29-detail):

```
public function loginByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    /* @var $class IdentityInterface */
    $class = $this->identityClass;
    $identity = $class::findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type);
    if ($identity && $this->login($identity)) {
        return $identity;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So you can also call it in your custom auth method:

```
$identity = $user->loginByAccessToken($accessToken, get_class($this));
```

See for example how it's implemented in [yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/QueryParamAuth.php).

And you also need to return `$identity`, not `$user`. Also handling failure is missing in your code. See how it's implemented in built-in auth methods:

- [HttpBasicAuth](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/HttpBasicAuth.php)
- [HttpBearerAuth](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/HttpBearerAuth.php)
- [QueryParamAuth](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/QueryParamAuth.php)

More from official docs:

- [yii\web\User login()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login%28%29-detail)
- [yii\filters\auth\AuthInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-authinterface.html#authenticate%28%29-detail)

**Update:**

Nothing forces you to use `loginByAccessToken()`, I just mentioned it as an example.

Here is an example of custom auth method that I wrote quite a while ago, not sure if it's 100% safe and true, but I hope it can help you to understand these details:

Custom auth method:

```
<?php

namespace api\components;

use yii\filters\auth\AuthMethod;

class HttpPostAuth extends AuthMethod
{
    /**
     * @see yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth
     */
    public $auth;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function authenticate($user, $request, $response)
    {
        $username = $request->post('username');
        $password = $request->post('password');

        if ($username !== null && $password !== null) {
            $identity = call_user_func($this->auth, $username, $password);
            if ($identity !== null) {
                $user->switchIdentity($identity);
            } else {
                $this->handleFailure($response);
            }
            return $identity;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage in REST controller:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpPostAuth::className(),
        'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
            $user = new User;
            $user->domain_name = $username;

            // This will validate password according with LDAP
            if (!$user->validatePassword($password)) {
                return null;
            }

            return User::find()->username($username)->one();
        },
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

Specifying `$auth` callable is also can be found in `HttpBasicAuth`.

Comment: Thanks. You cleared it up for me. I didn't reallise that my auth method should call the built in loginByAccessToken() which in turn will call my customised findIdentityByAccessToken() method.

Can I do the same for finding by username and password as I would like to customise that also? I can't see find the loginByAccessToken() equivalent.

Comment: Nothing forces you to use exactly that method. I just mentioned this as an example. I updated answer with another example.

Comment: Thank you. However I have two auth methods and therefore using class = 'composite' so a bit lost to do the callback method you have shown. Can't I keep the logic in the custom auth component and model?

Comment: You can pass configuration to each including auth method separately. See here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-compositeauth.html#$authMethods-detail